# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Retrieve/Remove DropDownList Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm creating an application were employees enter their First/Last Name, select their Department and Appointment from drop down lists. The CRUD Operations all work fine.

However, I need to remove the value(s) from the Appointments drop down list that have already been assigned to an employee. There can only be one employee per Appointment. So, I need to remove the Appointments from the Appointments drop down list after a user selects one.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0, C#, EntityFrameworkCore Code First and SQL Server 2016.

I'm attaching my code that I have now if someone could possible assist. Thank you in advance!

**Models**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public string TimeSlot { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModels**

```
public class EmployeeFormVM
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your First Name")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Last Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your Department")]
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your Appointment")]
    [Display(Name = "Appointment")]
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class WinTenDbContext : DbContext
{
    public WinTenDbContext(DbContextOptions<WinTenDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasKey(e => e.EmployeeID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.FirstName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();


        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.LastName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();            

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasKey(d => d.DepartmentID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .Property(d => d.Name)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
            .HasKey(a => a.AppointmentID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
            .Property(a => a.TimeSlot)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

**EmployeesController**

```
public class EmployeesController : Controller
{
    private readonly WinTenDbContext _context;

    public EmployeesController(WinTenDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Employees and their Departments
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var webAppDbContext = _context.Employees.Include(d => d.Department).Include(a => a.Appointment);
        return View(await webAppDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Employees/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = await _context.Employees
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
        var appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();

        var viewModel = new EmployeeFormVM
        {
            Departments = departments,
            Appointments = appointments
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EmployeeFormVM employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var emp = new Employee();
            {
                emp.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
                emp.LastName = employee.LastName;
                emp.DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID;
                emp.AppointmentID = employee.AppointmentID;
            }

            // Query DB to check if Employee exists with same First/Last Name
            Employee existingEmployee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FirstName == employee.FirstName && m.LastName == employee.LastName);
            if (existingEmployee != null)
            {
                // Display Error if duplicate employee
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An employee with this name has already registered");
                employee.Departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
                employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                return View(employee);
            }

            // Query DB to check if appointment has already been assigned to an employee
            Employee existingAppointment = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AppointmentID == employee.AppointmentID);
            if (existingAppointment != null)
            {
                // Display error if the appointment was already chosen
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "This appointment has already been taken. Please select another timeslot.");
                employee.Departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
                employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                return View(employee);
            }

            _context.Add(emp);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(employee);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employeevm = new EmployeeFormVM();
        {
            Employee employee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            employeevm.EmployeeID = employee.EmployeeID;
            employeevm.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
            employeevm.LastName = employee.LastName;

            // Retrieve list of Departments
            var departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
            employeevm.Departments = departments;
            // Set the selected department
            employeevm.DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID;

            // Retrieve list of Appointments
            var appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
            employeevm.Appointments = appointments;
            // Set the selected department
            employeevm.AppointmentID = employee.AppointmentID;
        }   
        return View(employeevm);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EmployeeFormVM vmEdit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Employee employee = _context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeID == vmEdit.EmployeeID);

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            employee.FirstName = vmEdit.FirstName;
            employee.LastName = vmEdit.LastName;
            employee.DepartmentID = vmEdit.DepartmentID;
            employee.AppointmentID = vmEdit.AppointmentID;

            try
            {
                _context.Update(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EmployeeExists(vmEdit.EmployeeID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(vmEdit);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = await _context.Employees
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var employee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        _context.Employees.Remove(employee);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool EmployeeExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Employees.Any(e => e.EmployeeID == id);
    }
}
```

**Create View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employees"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "validation-summary-errors" })
        //@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @style = "color: #cc0000" })
        //@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.LastName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.DepartmentID, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "DepartmentID", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.AppointmentID, new SelectList(Model.Appointments, "AppointmentID", "TimeSlot"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    }
```

**Edit View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employees"))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.LastName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.DepartmentID, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "DepartmentID", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.AppointmentID, new SelectList(Model.Appointments, "AppointmentID", "TimeSlot"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.EmployeeID)

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Add a field isFilled, and when an employee selects an appointment you populate it and filter on that

Comment: @johnny5, Is there a way or query that when it first retrieves the appointment values I can first check the Employees table and only load the Appointment values that are not in the Employees table based on the AppointmentID.

Comment: @Brian, can you please re-phrase your comment? Do you want to filter only the appointments that do not have an associated employee?

Comment: @ironstone13, I would like to retrieve all appointment values to the drop down list that have not already been added to the employees table. So, if an emploee selects Sept 27, 2017 - Morning Slot 1 then that value will no longer get retrieved to the appointment drop down list. This way, the user only sees values from the appointment drop down list that have already not bee chosen.

Comment: @Brian like I said when an employee selects an appointment the Boolean isFilled is set.  When the next user goes to pick an appointment they will load the page and your server only returns appointments that aren't filled what are you confused on

Comment: @johnny5, I don't have a Boolean isFilled in my database. I'm looking to see if this can be handled within the code itself by calling a query to retrieve all appointment values to the drop down list whose value(s) have not already been added to the employees table. The appointments table has a PK called AppointmentID, so I just need a way to retrieve the appointment values to the drop down list whose AppointmentID values have not already been added to the employees table.

Comment: @Brian okay then filter on by appointments who are not in the list of appointments assigned to the employees same concept with out the field

Comment: @12seconds, I have a list of 385 possibly values that get retrieved to the Appointments drop down list. That table contains AppointmentID and TimeSlot. When a user selects his/her TimeSlot from the drop down list that value (AppointmentID) gets added to the Employees table. I just need help with the query that retrieves the list of Appointments to the drop down list whose values have not already been added to the employees table based on the (AppointmentID).

Comment: @Brian, why not use *LINQ* query for this?
Something like `Appointments.Where(x=>!x.Employees.Any())`
*No additional fields are needed*, no `isFilled` or any of that - you already have everything in your model

Comment: @ironstone13, Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for. A way to check within code. Would I apply that to the [HttpGet] Create Method on **var appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();** along with the [HttpPost] Create Method on **employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();** since those are the two areas that are retrieving the appointment values to the drop down list.

Comment: @Brian, how about something like this:
`var appointments = _context.Appointments.Include(x=>x.Employees).Where(x=>!x.Employees.Any()).ToList()`

Comment: @ironstone13, That worked exactly as needed. Now, do I need to add that same code to the other areas I mentioned above?

Comment: @Brian, each time you need that data filtered, for example in GET methods, you will need to apply that query. To reuse code you might want to extract it to a repository class of some sort.  For POST methods, you might skip it, unless you want to do a validation ( if you suspect the user could have tampered with the input). Does that answer the question, or would you like more details?

Comment: @Brian, please let me know if your problem is solved. Do you have any other issues? If not, please do not hesitate to mark my answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @ironstone13 I’m sorry I was away, yes, your solution that you provided was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your help!! I also just read what you posted on concurrency check, how would I handle that on POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple LINQ query like below:

```
var appointments = _context.Appointments.Include(x=>x.Employees).Where(x=>!x.Em‌​ployees.Any()).ToLis‌​t();
```

If you need to reuse the code, you could use the [repository pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) and extract this code to another class.

Each time you need that data filtered, for example in GET methods, you will need to apply that query.
For POST methods, you might skip it, unless:

1. You want to do **validation**. If you suspect the user could have tampered with the input, and somehow provided an invalid ID, then you might want to check against that filtered data again.
2. You want to manage **concurrency** - suppose two users requested the page at the same time, and specific appointment slot was available. What if **both** of those employees selected the same time slot? In this case a check on POST would be helpful, to prevent invalid data